# Subscribe global javascript events in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js

Im implementing Ziggeo (http://ziggeo.com/) in our Ember JS application, and Ziggeo has a Javascript SDK where you subscribe to events like this

```
ZiggeoApi.Events.on("submitted", function (data) {
   alert("Submitted a new video with token '" + data.video.token + "'!");
});
```

I manage to receive the event if I add it globally in JS like this:

```
<script>
  ZiggeoApi.token = 'myToken';
  ZiggeoApi.Events.on("submitted", function (data) {
    console.log('video updated: ' + data);
  });
</script>
```

But how can I listen to global events in Ember (controller)?

I tried this, and it somehow worked, except for that "this" context will not be the controller, so I cant call other ember components, like the store, or store.createRecord, etc.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  ziggeoRecordDone: ZiggeoApi.Events.on("submitted", (function(data) {
      console.log("Ziggeo Record Done YEAH; HURRA");
      ZiggeoApi.videoOnLoad = data.video.token;
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be:

1. Override the controller's `init` function
2. Add `initZiggeo` function, to bind your ziggeo events
3. To use `store` inside your callbacks you must declare another variable that references `this`, I used var `self  = this;`.
4. If your callbacks will update any controller or model property, you will need to use the ember loop (More info about [run loop](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/))

Your controller will look like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

//Initializing controller 
init:function(){

this._super();     

this.initZiggeo();
},

initZiggeo:function(){

   var self = this;

   ZiggeoApi.Events.on("submitted", function(data) {

     //If you want your events update the ember code
     Ember.run.once(self,function(){

       console.log("Ziggeo Record Done YEAH; HURRA");

       ZiggeoApi.videoOnLoad = data.video.token;

     });

   });
}
```